# what do you call starting the smoking activity

Tags: word-request

When anyone starts smoking, he/she "fire" the cigarette.

I am sure the "fire" word is not correct. so what should I say?

I tried using the dictionary to translate from my language to English, but all I got is:

1. "burn" the cigarette?
2. "grill" the cigarette?

which I am sure is not correct in English.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He or she **lights** *a* cigarette (cigar/pipe), unless we are talking about some cigarette that we want to reference as uniquely indentifiable, such as one that fell on the ground; in that case, use *the*.

When a person lacks matches or a cigarette lighter, he can ask someone "Do you have a **light**?"

Comment: "Messer, Gabel, Scher' und Licht – sind für kleine Kinder nicht." -> An old german saying that also refers to fire as "light" :)

Answer (score 8):

You *light* a cigarette or just *light up*.

Note that this tracks with what you do to start a fire: you *light a fire*, or *light the wood on fire*.

A cigarette that is burning is a *lit cigarette*.

About *lighting up*—if you were to read, "George lit up and took a drag," you should understand this to mean he had lighted (or lit) a cigarette and then drew in air through it, taking smoke into his lungs. Despite not saying so, this unambiguously refers to a cigarette, unless context indicates otherwise.

Comment: To add a bit, the only other word I can think of for this action is "ignite" and it is restricted in usage.

Comment: @JasonPatterson: For cigarettes, to? I only know ignite for "firing up" a car.

Comment: @phresnel No, I agree, "light a cigarette" is always used.  ErikE's answer indicated that we use "light" as the verb to start fires in general.  I was just adding that ignite is also used in some settings.

Comment: You can set something on fire. (You wouldn't say that you "set a cigarette", of course.)

Comment: You also wouldn't generally say *ignite a cigarette*, as ignition is a special word that generally refers to fuses or fuel, and while cigarettes are definitely fuel in that they will burn, they aren't considered fuel for the benefit of something besides themselves.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "lighting/lit **up**." In fact, by adding "up" (and even "down") to other verbs one could describe George's entire experience, from start to finish, of enjoying "one": ... "George twisted one up, then fired it [one] up, and proceeded to burn 'er [one] down (with several bogartishly long tokes)!"  CC: @MarcoDinatsoli

Comment: Agree with all above.  Only light is used. *Spark a cigarette* is more likely as a playful way to say it than *ignite*, with *ignite* being intentionally over-technical.  *Spark up a cigarette* is understood, but colorful.  *Can I get a light?*, *Can I bum a light?*, *Light me up?* examples in question form.